# Will a USB 2.0 5400RPM External HDD for Time Machine slow down my SSD?

Tags: macos, time-machine, ssd, external-disk, usb

Will a USB 2.0 5400RPM External HDD for Time Machine slow down my SSD?  I am new to Mac and I don't know how often Time Machine works with the drive.

Answer (score 1):

I use a USB 2.0 external hard drive for Time Machine, and I have not seen any changes in speed.  Time Machine works pretty quietly and effortlessly in the background without slowing down the Mac's performance.  According to the Time Machine System Preferences pane,

> Time Machine keeps:
>
> - Hourly backups for the past 24 hours
> - Daily backups for the past month
> - Weekly backups for all previous months
>
> The oldest backups are deleted when your disk becomes full.